# Crash while making call in pjsip-2.6 in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, sip, voip, pjsip

I have successfully compiled pjsip for all the architectures and able to register sip. But when i try to make call using `pjsua_call_make_call` then app is crashing.

Below the method which i am using to make call.

```
- (void)makeCallTo:(char*)destUri
{
    pj_status_t status;
    pj_str_t uri = pj_str(destUri);

    status = pjsua_verify_sip_url(destUri);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE,  "Invalid URL \"%s\".", uri));
        pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "Invalid URL", status);
        return;
    }

    status = pjsua_call_make_call(_acc_id, &uri, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
        error_exit("Error making call", status);
    }
}
```

Below is the  sip trace,

```
13:15:21.513   pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #0 to sip:9876543210@myserver.com
13:15:21.513    pjsua_aud.c  .Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-2
13:15:21.513    pjsua_aud.c  ..Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
13:15:21.514 coreaudio_dev.  ...Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
13:15:23.655 coreaudio_dev. !...core audio stream started
13:15:23.656  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: initializing media..
13:15:23.656  pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 192.168.0.103:4000
13:15:23.656  pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 192.168.0.103:4001
13:15:23.657  pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 192.168.0.103:4002
13:15:23.657  pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 192.168.0.103:4003
13:15:23.657  pjsua_media.c  ..Media index 0 selected for audio call 0
Assertion failed: ((status=pjmedia_sdp_validate(local))==PJ_SUCCESS), function pjmedia_sdp_neg_create_w_local_offer, file ../src/pjmedia/sdp_neg.c, line 111.
```

**Any help will be very appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use cocoapods.

Add the following line to your Podfile and run pod install command.

`pod 'pjsip'`

https://github.com/chebur/pjsip